# Вызвать конструктор из конструктора

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Попытка вызова конструктора не дает собрать библиотеку, т.к.:

> error C2614: yami::vlc::VlcMediaPlayer: недопустимая инициализация
>   члена: "VlcMediaPlayer" не является базовым классом или членом

```
public ref class VlcMediaPlayer
{
public:
    ...
    explicit VlcMediaPlayer(array<String^>^ args);
    explicit VlcMediaPlayer(array<String^>^ args, LogMessage^ log);
    ...
}
```

```
VlcMediaPlayer::VlcMediaPlayer(array<String^>^ args) :
    _vlcData(nullptr),
    _vlcInstance(nullptr),
    _vlcMediaPlayer(nullptr),
    _media(nullptr),
    _pausable(false),
    _isPlaying(false),
    _vlcAudio(nullptr),
    _vlcEvents(nullptr)
    //_vlcVideo(nullptr)
{
    ...
}
VlcMediaPlayer::VlcMediaPlayer(array<String^>^ args, LogMessage^ log) : VlcMediaPlayer(args)
{
    ...
}
```

Как вызвать другой конструктор?

Comment: Обьясните, что за конструктор вы вызываете. Свой? Это не нужно делать. Конструктор базового класса? У вас нет базового класса, и его конструктора, соответственно тоже нет. Пока не проясните что это за конструктор - вопрос не понятен.

Comment: @test123: `Свой? Это не нужно делать.` Вы предлагаете дублировать код?

Comment: Кажется понял, а вы пробовали явно указать VlcMediaPlayer::VlcMediaPlayer(array<String^>^ args, LogMessage^ log) : VlcMediaPlayer::VlcMediaPlayer(args)  { ... }?

Comment: @test123: Да, думаю что все возможные варианты перепробовал, но может есть вариант вызвать его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, в `Visual Studio 2012`, нет поддержки `C++0x`, а в спецификации языка написано, что конструкторы делегаты не доступны в `c++` ниже чем [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11). Это касается вроде бы как только [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli).

Подробнее можно почитать тут на 295 странице в разделе `F.3.1 Delegating constructors`: [Standart master - Ecma-372](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-372.pdf)